# display record above 10 days from the time created using sql vba access

Tags: vba, ms-access

this what I'm doing right now which is long cut

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM COMPUTER_LIST")
With rs
    Do Until .EOF
        DateDiffValue = DateDiff("d", CDate(!created_date), Date)
        If DateDiffValue > 10 And DateDiffValue < 21 Then
            'Display the Record Here using Listview
        End If
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

how can i make as shortcut query?

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM COMPUTER_LIST
    WHERE created_date > Datediff('d', created_date,Date()) AND\
          created_date < DateAdd('d', 20,created_date)")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the title of the post at all.  You should write your post like you are trying to explain your problem to a child.  Not just because children are some of the best programmers.   Capitalization and punctuation is also important.

You code suggests that you want to select all the records between 10 and 21 days ago.

```
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "SELECT COMPUTER_LIST.*" & vbNewLine & _
      "FROM COMPUTER_LIST" & vbNewLine & _
      "WHERE (((DateValue([created_date]))>=Date()-20 And (DateValue([created_date]))<=Date()-10));"

Set rs = Db.OpenRecordset(SQL)
```